# Integrating $2(x+y+z)$ over the volume of $x^2+y^2+4(z-1)^2=4$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Consider the ellipsoid:
$$x^2+y^2+4(z-1)^2=4.$$
This surface can be parametrised by:
$$\vec{r}(u,v) = 2\sin(u)\cos(v)\vec{i}+2\sin(u)\sin(v)\vec{j}+(1+\cos(u))\vec{k}$$
with $$u \in [0,\pi], \quad v \in [0,2\pi].$$
If now we integrate $f(x,y,z)= 2x+2y+2z$ over the volume enclosed by this surface, it's easy to see that the result should be
$$I=2(\bar{x}+\bar{y}+\bar{z})V_{\text{ellipsoid}}= \frac{32}{3\pi}.$$ However, if I try to do the integral without using centroids, I get:
$$
\int_{2sin(0)cos(0)}^{2sin(\pi)cos(2\pi)}dx\int dy\int dz  f(x,y,z).$$
Where I have only filled in the first integral bounds because obviously that term becomes zero (you integrate from $0$ to $0$).
Why does this happen? Is my parametrisation wrong?

Comment: I believe your $\pi$ should be in the numerator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parametrization is for the surface, not for the volume. You need to include the radius to account for the inside. It should be

$${\mathbf r}(u,v) = 2r \sin(u) \cos(v) {\mathbf i} + 2r \sin(u) \sin(v) {\mathbf j} + (1+r \cos(u)) {\mathbf k}.$$

The bounds are

$$0 \leq r \leq 1, \quad 0 \leq u \leq \pi, \quad 0 \leq v \leq 2 \pi.$$

The triple integral is

$$\begin{align} I & = \int f \, dV \\ & = \int_0^{2 \pi}\hspace{-3pt} \int_0^{\pi} \hspace{-3pt} \int_0^1 2(\underbrace{2r \sin(u) \cos(v)}_x + \underbrace{2r \sin(u) \sin(v)}_y + \underbrace{(1+r \cos(u))}_z) \cdot \underbrace{4 r^2 \sin(u)}_{\text{Jacobian}} \, dr \, du \, dv. \end{align}$$

When you multiply you will be left with integrals containing $\cos(v)$, $\sin(v)$ and $\sin(u)\cos(u)$ which, over the bounds selected, will be zero. The only remaining integral is of $r^2 \sin(u)$. Therefore

$$I = 8 \int_0^{2\pi} \hspace{-3pt} \int_0^{\pi} \hspace{-3pt} \int_0^1 r^2 \sin(u) \, dr \, du \, dv = \frac{32 \pi}{3}.$$

Comment: Would you say parametrising the volume first is the best option here?

Comment: @JefPauwels Yes. The corresponding surfaces can be found by setting one of the parameters constant. In this case, the radius.